# How to remove the background color from ActiveX option button?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, activex, background-color, activexobject

I'm currently creating an IT support form, in excel, to be filled in and then on the press of a button it will save the data to another sheet in the document. My question is, how can I remove the background color from an ActiveX option button so it has the same color as my boxes? If this can't be done, is there anyway I can set it so that the background color of the option button is the same as Excel 2010's Accent 3 - 20% (the hex color code for it is #ebf1de). I understand that it uses MS access codes but don't know how I can convert hex codes to this or anything. Thanks

Comment: Personally I would prefer a "form" to be just Excel cells with Data Validation. Controls force the user into using the mouse to go from input to input.

Comment: I am using a cell based form but have decided to add in these buttons to limit the responses the user can give. The design I have can be seen here: [link](http://s7.postimg.org/gkbvhebm3/image.png).

Comment: Data Validation is all about limiting choices. But it does have some limitations indeed.